# How to send multiple results fetched from a database as a response to POST?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I have an array of names to be searched for in the database, I used a for each function to iterate through it and I'm able to get these results. Now where I'm struggling is how do I send back both these results as responses, currently I'm only able to send the first fetched result.

I know the issue is arising due to res.write being called multiple times, but I don't know how to send multiple html responses without it.

```
app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
    // x = req.body.name;
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });

const names = req.body.name.split(',');
console.log(names);

names.forEach(function(){
  //--------------FINDING RECORDS INTO THE DATABASE--------------//
  let sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
  con.query(sqlQuery, names, function(error, results){
    if(error){
        callback(error);
        return;
    }

    if(results.length){
    console.log("Found in DB");

    // res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"><title>Document</title>');

    //--------------SCRIPTS--------------//
    res.write('<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');

    //--------------CSS------------------//   
    res.write('<style> * { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }body { background: #ecf1f5;font:14px "Open Sans", sans-serif; text-align:center; } .tile{ width: 100%; background:#fff; border-radius:5px; box-shadow:0px 2px 3px -1px rgba(151, 171, 187, 0.7); float:left; transform-style: preserve-3d; margin: 10px 5px;} .header{ border-bottom:1px solid #ebeff2; padding:19px 0; text-align:center; color:#59687f; font-size:600;font-size:19px;position:relative;}.banner-img {padding: 5px 5px 0;}  .banner-img img { width: 100%; border-radius: 5px; }.dates{border:1px solid #ebeff2;border-radius:5px; padding:20px 0px; margin:10px 20px; font-size:16px; color:#5aadef;font-weight:600; overflow:auto;} .dates div{ float:left; width:100%; text-align:center;position:relative;} .dates strong,.stats strong{display:block; color:#adb8c2; font-size:11px;font-weight:700;} .dates span{ width:1px;  height:40px; position:absolute; right:0; top:0; background:#ebeff2;} .stats{border-top:1px solid #ebeff2;   background:#f7f8fa;  overflow:auto;  padding:15px 0; font-size:16px; color:#59687f; font-weight:600; border-radius: 0 0 5px ;} .stats div{border-right:1px solid #ebeff2; width: 50%; float:left;text-align:center} .stats div:nth-of-type(3){border:none;}</style></head>');

    //--------------HTML-----------------//
    res.write('<body>    <div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"> <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> <div class="tile"><div class="wrapper"><div class="header">User Details</div> <div class="banner-img"><img src=' + results[0].Avatar_url+ '/></div><div class="dates"><div class="start"> <strong>BIO</strong>' + results[0] .Bio + '<span></span> </div> <div class="stats"><div><strong>USERNAME</strong> '+ results[0].username +'</div><div><strong>NAME</strong>'+ results[0].Name +  '</div></div><div class="stats"><div><strong>PUBLIC REPOSITORIES</strong>'+ results[0].Public_repos+'</div><div><strong>PUBLIC GISTS</strong>'+results[0].Public_gists+'</div></div><div class="stats"><div><strong>FOLLOWERS</strong>'+results[0].Followers+'</div><div><strong>FOLLOWING</strong>'+results[0].Following+' </div></div></div></div></div></body></html>');

    // res.end();
    }else{
    console.log("Not Found in DB");
    getUser(x);
    }
});
})

function getUser(name){
  fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${name}`)
   .then(function(response) {
     return response.json();
   })
   .then(function(json) {
    //--------------INSERTING RECORDS INTO THE DATABASE--------------//
    con.query("INSERT INTO Users (username, Name, Avatar_URL, Bio, Public_repos, Public_gists, Followers, Following) VALUES ('"+json.login+"', '"+json.name+"', '"+json.avatar_url+"','"+json.bio+"','"+json.public_repos+"','"+json.public_gists+"','"+json.followers+"','"+json.following+"')")
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"><title>Document</title>');

    //--------------SCRIPTS--------------//
    res.write('<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');

    //--------------CSS------------------//   
    res.write('<style> * { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }body { background: #ecf1f5;font:14px "Open Sans", sans-serif; text-align:center; } .tile{ width: 100%; background:#fff; border-radius:5px; box-shadow:0px 2px 3px -1px rgba(151, 171, 187, 0.7); float:left; transform-style: preserve-3d; margin: 10px 5px;} .header{ border-bottom:1px solid #ebeff2; padding:19px 0; text-align:center; color:#59687f; font-size:600;font-size:19px;position:relative;}.banner-img {padding: 5px 5px 0;}  .banner-img img { width: 100%; border-radius: 5px; }.dates{border:1px solid #ebeff2;border-radius:5px; padding:20px 0px; margin:10px 20px; font-size:16px; color:#5aadef;font-weight:600; overflow:auto;} .dates div{ float:left; width:100%; text-align:center;position:relative;} .dates strong,.stats strong{display:block; color:#adb8c2; font-size:11px;font-weight:700;} .dates span{ width:1px;  height:40px; position:absolute; right:0; top:0; background:#ebeff2;} .stats{border-top:1px solid #ebeff2;   background:#f7f8fa;  overflow:auto;  padding:15px 0; font-size:16px; color:#59687f; font-weight:600; border-radius: 0 0 5px ;} .stats div{border-right:1px solid #ebeff2; width: 50%; float:left;text-align:center} .stats div:nth-of-type(3){border:none;}</style></head>');

    //--------------HTML-----------------//
    res.write('<body>    <div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"> <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> <div class="tile"><div class="wrapper"><div class="header">User Details</div> <div class="banner-img"><img src=' + json.avatar_url+ '/></div><div class="dates"><div class="start"> <strong>BIO</strong>' + json.bio + '<span></span> </div> <div class="stats"><div><strong>USERNAME</strong> '+ json.login +'</div><div><strong>NAME</strong>'+ json.name +  '</div></div><div class="stats"><div><strong>PUBLIC REPOSITORIES</strong>'+ json.public_repos+'</div><div><strong>PUBLIC GISTS</strong>'+json.public_gists+'</div></div><div class="stats"><div><strong>FOLLOWERS</strong>'+json.followers+'</div><div><strong>FOLLOWING</strong>'+json.following+' </div></div></div></div></div></body></html>');

    res.end();
    });
 };
})
```

I want each result to be printed together.

**UPDATE** -  So I solved the can't set headers problem and get no error now. However I'm still not able to print multiple results. I've updated the full code with the CSS as well. I am using bootstrap cards and need to print multiple cards side by side.

Comment: You are not looping through your array, hence the single item

Comment: I do, I get the 'Can't set headers after they are sent' error

Comment: Instead of `forEach()` try to call the mySQL with `... WHERE username IN (?)...` and then passing the array as `names.join(',')`. This will search all names in a single query a return all records in one array.

Answer (score 0):

Please declare an array, and push the elements in the array, and send the array as response.

```
app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
const names = req.body.name.split(',');

names.forEach(function(){
  //--------------FINDING RECORDS INTO THE DATABASE--------------//
  let sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
  con.query(sqlQuery, names, function(error, results){
    if(error){
        callback(error);
        return;
    }

    if(results.length){
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    let result_array = [];
    result_array.push('<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"><title>Document</title>');

//--------------HTML SENDING THE RESPONSE-----------------//
    result_array.push('<body><div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"> <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> <div class="tile"><div class="wrapper"><div class="header">User Details</div> <div class="banner-img"><img src=' + results[0].Avatar_url+ '/></div><div class="dates"><div class="start"> <strong>BIO</strong>' + results[0].Bio + '<span></span> </div> <div class="stats"><div><strong>USERNAME</strong> '+ results[0].username +'</div><div><strong>NAME</strong>'+ results[0].Name +'</body></html>'); 
    res.send(result_array);

    }else{
    console.log("Not Found in DB");
    getUser(x);
    }
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be.

```
app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
    const names = req.body.name.split(',');

    names.forEach(function(){
      //--------------FINDING RECORDS INTO THE DATABASE--------------//
      let sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
      con.query(sqlQuery, names, function(error, results){
        if(error){
            callback(error);
            return;
        }

        if(results.length){
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    let bodyData = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"><title>Document</title>';

    //--------------HTML SENDING THE RESPONSE-----------------//
        bodyData += '<body><div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"> <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> <div class="tile"><div class="wrapper"><div class="header">User Details</div> <div class="banner-img"><img src=' + results[0].Avatar_url+ '/></div><div class="dates"><div class="start"> <strong>BIO</strong>' + results[0].Bio + '<span></span> </div> <div class="stats"><div><strong>USERNAME</strong> '+ results[0].username +'</div><div><strong>NAME</strong>'+ results[0].Name +'</body></html>'; 
        res.write(bodyData);

        res.end();
        }else{
        console.log("Not Found in DB");
        getUser(x);
        }
    });
    })
```